# Aplicar evento a nav-tabs hecho en Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Buenos días, tengo un `nav-tabs` hecho en Bootstrap, que en uno de sus elementos crea una tabla de datos en un div vació. Necesito que al cambiar de pestaña en el `nav-tab`, ese div se vacíe, pero no consigo que se reconozca alguna función añadida a esos botones. Aquí esta el fragmento que corresponde al `nav-tab`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#crInforme" data-toggle="tab" onclick="limpiar()";>Crear Informe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#listado" data-toggle="tab">Lista de informes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Como veis, le he puesto un evento `onclick` a la una de las pestañas, para que al cambiar se ejecute una función sencilla que tengo en un fichero js:

```
function limpiar(){
  $('#info').html(''); }
```

Con esto solo pretendo que al cambiar de pestaña se limpie ese div, pero no consigo que funcione.

Comment: ¿En las herramientas de desarrollador marca algún error al hacer click?

Comment: hola, supongo que será una typo, pero tienes un punto y coma `;`justo antes del cierre del `<a>`, cuando debería estar encerrado dentro de las comillas: `<li><a href="#crInforme" data-toggle="tab" onclick="limpiar();">Crear Informe</a></li>`

Comment: ¿A que hace referencia #info? Supongo que será al div, pero no veo que lo indiques.

Comment: puedes mostrar el contenedor que quieres mostrar o minimamente su extructura, ya que el codigo esta imcompleto y nose donde realmente esta #div para decirte si estas haciendo algo mal o no.